# For loop on variable name and function in R

Tags: r, raster

This simple command below works perfectly:

```
pts.cnt1.1deg <- rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg, fun=function(r){r>=1})
```

However, I need to do that for many values (1:100). For instance, I tried this option bellows and it doesn't work this way.

```
for(i in 1:100){
    pts.cnt[i].1deg <- rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg, fun=function(r){r>=[i]})
}
```

Taking the example above, **how can I include a loop correctly on that command?**

Comment: You want to create 100 different variables? That can be a headache to work with in R. better to store related values like that in a list. Things are much easier to work with that way. `pts.cnt.1deg <- lapply(1:100, function(i) rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg, fun=function(r){r>=i})` and then you get values out with  `pts.cnt.1deg[[1]]`, `pts.cnt.1deg[[2]]`, etc...

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. I did exactly as you suggested. Now all the count variables are stored in a list and are called as you said `pts.cnt.1deg[[1]]` . Totally agree, much easier in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a loop like this

```
pts.cnt.1deg <- list()
for(i in 1:100){
    pts.cnt.1deg[[i]] <- rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg, fun=function(r){r>=[i]})
}
```

But it seems to me, that, memory permitting, it would be simpler to do

```
x <- rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg)
```

And then subset `x` as needed

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a loop, its slow and really only a work-around you'll have to undo later.
Convert the raster to points, then split out the spdf by your factor. Made the assumption that you would want to round the degrees to a significant digit or so.

```
x <- rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg)
x.list<-split(x,round(x$value,-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with MrFlick that there are better ways to do it.  What you're asking for can be done with the `assign(x, value)` function

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    assign(paste0("pts.cnt", i, ".1deg"), rasterToPoints(boxCnt.1deg, fun = function(r) { r >= 1 }))
}
```

Comment: But don't do that. You know the next question will be "how do I do X over my 100 variables?" and we'll have to explain `get` and the user *really* doesn't need that.

Comment: You're not wrong, but there have been times I have actually needed to do something like that.  I figured since MrFlick had "advice" covered, I'd answer the question literally ;)

Comment: Definitely seems like the right answer to the wrong question.